# From text to ascii art from CodinGame practice puzzle

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

On CodingGame, there is a [Puzzle](https://www.codingame.com/ide/puzzle/ascii-art) that ask to write words with ascii art. 
I solve the puzzle then tried to golf it. What improvement can I do on it?

```
INPUT
>>> 20
>>> 11
>>> MANHATTAN
>>>   .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .-----------------. .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------. 
>>> | .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
>>> | |      __      | || |   ______     | || |     ______   | || |  ________    | || |  _________   | || |  _________   | || |    ______    | || |  ____  ____  | || |     _____    | || |     _____    | || |  ___  ____   | || |   _____      | || | ____    ____ | || | ____  _____  | || |     ____     | || |   ______     | || |    ___       | || |  _______     | || |    _______   | || |  _________   | || | _____  _____ | || | ____   ____  | || | _____  _____ | || |  ____  ____  | || |  ____  ____  | || |   ________   | || |    ______    | |
>>> | |     /  \     | || |  |_   _ \    | || |   .' ___  |  | || | |_   ___ `.  | || | |_   ___  |  | || | |_   ___  |  | || |  .' ___  |   | || | |_   ||   _| | || |    |_   _|   | || |    |_   _|   | || | |_  ||_  _|  | || |  |_   _|     | || ||_   \  /   _|| || ||_   \|_   _| | || |   .'    `.   | || |  |_   __ \   | || |  .'   '.     | || | |_   __ \    | || |   /  ___  |  | || | |  _   _  |  | || ||_   _||_   _|| || ||_  _| |_  _| | || ||_   _||_   _|| || | |_  _||_  _| | || | |_  _||_  _| | || |  |  __   _|  | || |   / _ __ `.  | |
>>> | |    / /\ \    | || |    | |_) |   | || |  / .'   \_|  | || |   | |   `. \ | || |   | |_  \_|  | || |   | |_  \_|  | || | / .'   \_|   | || |   | |__| |   | || |      | |     | || |      | |     | || |   | |_/ /    | || |    | |       | || |  |   \/   |  | || |  |   \ | |   | || |  /  .--.  \  | || |    | |__) |  | || | /  .-.  \    | || |   | |__) |   | || |  |  (__ \_|  | || | |_/ | | \_|  | || |  | |    | |  | || |  \ \   / /   | || |  | | /\ | |  | || |   \ \  / /   | || |   \ \  / /   | || |  |_/  / /    | || |  |_/____) |  | |
>>> | |   / ____ \   | || |    |  __'.   | || |  | |         | || |   | |    | | | || |   |  _|  _   | || |   |  _|      | || | | |    ____  | || |   |  __  |   | || |      | |     | || |   _  | |     | || |   |  __'.    | || |    | |   _   | || |  | |\  /| |  | || |  | |\ \| |   | || |  | |    | |  | || |    |  ___/   | || | | |   | |    | || |   |  __ /    | || |   '.___`-.   | || |     | |      | || |  | '    ' |  | || |   \ \ / /    | || |  | |/  \| |  | || |    > `' <    | || |    \ \/ /    | || |     .'.' _   | || |    /  ___.'  | |
>>> | | _/ /    \ \_ | || |   _| |__) |  | || |  \ `.___.'\  | || |  _| |___.' / | || |  _| |___/ |  | || |  _| |_       | || | \ `.___]  _| | || |  _| |  | |_  | || |     _| |_    | || |  | |_' |     | || |  _| |  \ \_  | || |   _| |__/ |  | || | _| |_\/_| |_ | || | _| |_\   |_  | || |  \  `--'  /  | || |   _| |_      | || | \  `-'  \_   | || |  _| |  \ \_  | || |  |`\____) |  | || |    _| |_     | || |   \ `--' /   | || |    \ ' /     | || |  |   /\   |  | || |  _/ /'`\ \_  | || |    _|  |_    | || |   _/ /__/ |  | || |    |_|       | |
>>> | ||____|  |____|| || |  |_______/   | || |   `._____.'  | || | |________.'  | || | |_________|  | || | |_____|      | || |  `._____.'   | || | |____||____| | || |    |_____|   | || |  `.___.'     | || | |____||____| | || |  |________|  | || ||_____||_____|| || ||_____|\____| | || |   `.____.'   | || |  |_____|     | || |  `.___.\__|  | || | |____| |___| | || |  |_______.'  | || |   |_____|    | || |    `.__.'    | || |     \_/      | || |  |__/  \__|  | || | |____||____| | || |   |______|   | || |  |________|  | || |    (_)       | |
>>> | |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
>>> | '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
>>>  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'
```

```
OUPUT:
 .----------------.  .----------------.  .-----------------. .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .----------------.  .-----------------.
| .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. || .--------------. |
| | ____    ____ | || |      __      | || | ____  _____  | || |  ____  ____  | || |      __      | || |  _________   | || |  _________   | || |      __      | || | ____  _____  | |
| ||_   \  /   _|| || |     /  \     | || ||_   \|_   _| | || | |_   ||   _| | || |     /  \     | || | |  _   _  |  | || | |  _   _  |  | || |     /  \     | || ||_   \|_   _| | |
| |  |   \/   |  | || |    / /\ \    | || |  |   \ | |   | || |   | |__| |   | || |    / /\ \    | || | |_/ | | \_|  | || | |_/ | | \_|  | || |    / /\ \    | || |  |   \ | |   | |
| |  | |\  /| |  | || |   / ____ \   | || |  | |\ \| |   | || |   |  __  |   | || |   / ____ \   | || |     | |      | || |     | |      | || |   / ____ \   | || |  | |\ \| |   | |
| | _| |_\/_| |_ | || | _/ /    \ \_ | || | _| |_\   |_  | || |  _| |  | |_  | || | _/ /    \ \_ | || |    _| |_     | || |    _| |_     | || | _/ /    \ \_ | || | _| |_\   |_  | |
| ||_____||_____|| || ||____|  |____|| || ||_____|\____| | || | |____||____| | || ||____|  |____|| || |   |_____|    | || |   |_____|    | || ||____|  |____|| || ||_____|\____| | |
| |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | || |              | |
| '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' || '--------------' |
 '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'  '----------------'
```

#### Python 3: 145 bytes

```
i=input;l=int(i());h=int(i());t=[ord(c)-65if c.isalpha()else 26for c in i().upper()]
while h:h-=1;r=i();print(''.join(r[j*l:l*(j+1)] for j in t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VdNb9pAEL37V8zNdip2S6rmEEql/ID2lFs2WkeUCCMEiBBVlfa/051drz0za4Xea0vB4fF2Zt58GY5/zpvD/svl0i7b/fH9vNj5@7lqq7pebIZ/z8unw@lXtapnd1/bV1ip9u1ld9y8VPV697aG27vXwwlW0O7B09X78bg@VfVz8XvT7tawud/MlvPFaek/WxxPaLQs1fbQ7qvT0/Zmd7@7qbaf5vUzoJUtWjnX9eVy@7mYz4sfL/ubh8fHh58FqJm4FEyYB6e8QOEkqsBN2IQh5pvDQbisjXeHRBcAvDhG0IRZOxAlZq9g1AnlpVfpdywWcTYdFTqYtgSEO8PsqN9/yEvvQurNedfzYmkwPGYW3xhvNH@jOb1ej745NIBhQlyIJYL9YVVC5yFhrgsZGpVjYzyCUXOM50LwjgQdjzsmJMMQcPhindThiLaAmCDZf0CxxKV6/YXShL2YGKIDoFQ0f5Q22NN5XjDJ4c@x@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@PsbPxO8OFZl8XS2Uo3ihnhNwZI42NCeCwm0xtveSwkV8zgoBctRnFkQIzVYsOE8oz4lflzNstfnhe0XPnOZc0B7KKrfML@a8w3R8l/35ZInLAJ880hsfCInbAJ81jxFw)

Comment: `(j+1)` can be `-~j`. The space between `]` and `for` can be omitted.

Comment: `c.isalpha()*(ord(c)-91)+26` is shorter than the `if`.

Comment: Is `?` the only non-alphabetic character?

Comment: @JonathanAllan, that seems to be the joker to replace _any_ non-alphabetic character, like in `tr --complement 'A-Z' '?'`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan yes. If a character is non-alphabetic, it's ASCII art must be the '?' art.

Comment: @DorianTurba for one less byte total, we we can multiply by `l` inside the comprehension assigned to `t` (which is just `l*`, once we use an indexing lookup rather than an `if-else`) and use `r[j-l:j]` :)

Comment: Yes, I see that in your answer. I remove the comment, thanks.

Comment: Is it allowed for the program to terminate with error after printing due to trying to read a line past the last line?

Comment: @xnor I don't know. You can try the code in the puzzle link provided in my question, the tests are in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>131 130 128 126</s>  125 bytes

```python
i=input
L=int(i())
exec("t=[L*[27,ord(c)%32][c.isalpha()]for c in i()]"+";r=i();print(''.join(r[j-L:j]for j in t))"*int(i()))
```

A few golfs of the provided code.

Note: I upper-cased `l` to `L` and replaced a couple of `;` with newlines just for legibility.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VdNb9swDL37VxABBtndIq3pYcC6Dui926m3KJCLrEMTDEmQZcAG6L9nomTZJGU0u88GajevTyQfv5we/pxe9rub83lzt9kdfp2qh/A81Zu6aarn38/rena6Wz5cLRcf3u2P3@p18@ZmsVqu9ebn04/Dy1PdrL7vj7CGzQ7CmdXs7ez2eBd@uz0c0Y5Servf7Orjcjt/@LiN5C2ST00zu8qemvN58b66vq6@PO2u7h8f779WoOfi0jBhAZzyApWXqAY/YROGWGgOD/FyLj09En0E8OIYQTPm3ECUmLuAUSeUl@/S71gs4mw@KnQwbRmIT4a5Ub//kJfehdRb8i7nxdFgeMwsvjHeaP5Gc3q5Hn1zGADLhPgYSwL7w1pB5yFjvgsZWl1iYzyCUXOM52PwngSdjnsmpMAQ8HhzXurwRFtEbJQc/kCxzKV6w4XShL2UGKIDQGmaP0ob7JkyL5jk@ONZfK5/9JhLVvv4xngdg/FGsdQzwHMV4nMw1DI3hwFjhZBotaGFC6yYBssMpnuwZxnmRngCo@Y4z3ngjZDdXMDwrIlV5zrEVONna4A1asTAC724bHVsJZ6XlJheR6BpEPkbaNRHjQ3j6NCY6JTligaesVSeJI7yjOW8ROS8MQwdg8hVwHBxZG1V3zFOTEPXW0pDEXRRkKyEYLEjHeflAR6mxgMU665r6YvN4UabI4dcNIfjOjBZnjdHwKwXxSyL1DlxRuoYyFQHb1Slw8l2rrk2qrHzFTeWKoouiwkeN76I7zO0Cj7xHFgcBjE0YTRxdTMsrTac2dwcediCBUeSX0xIILQ6niWTlGhoz0jM0LPdUqRJ6Myt2LpzWap49@fjJDFOieZwecbYuzUGQ2OJiDXJJMO6l9WgF9r5XMWccXtCR6ApiG5fjcW3lk5mHo7eIGmE6NeIAieEbztj@QbEYqpW5CC9PPh3NiSKGiGHbNkqvrucS4fxOayYdLEAYzH7zkprsbvGMLY@u880QGKO8XJINOh8nJ1N3wlePeuLWDpb@UExK/ymAGl8TAiPxRZ606OMheSKGRz0osUkjgyIdUZsmFieEb8yf94V@Svzgpbr0LmsOYBddJVP2H@NheZQ/P9bhcQJm7DQHBKLr9gJm7CAVX8B)**

1. When characters are alphabetical their ordinals are ranges \$[65,90]+[97,122]\$ which modulo \$32\$ are \$[1,27]+[1,27]=[1,27]\$. As such we can remove the `.upper()` and work with `ord(c)%32` in this case.
2. Rather than an `if-else` we can either use the fact that `False` is `0` and `True` is `1` and multiply (as originally suggested by manatwork in comments) or use list indexing for the two cases like above (`[27,ord(c)%32][c.isalpha()]` chooses the slice stop rather than its start).
3. We can save a little by replacing the `while` loop with the `exec` of a string of code produced using string multiplication.
4. We can save a byte by moving `t=...` into the `exec`-ed code so we do not have to assign to `h` at all. Another is saved by moving the repeated string's trailing `;` to the beginning so that the `t` assignment string doesn't require its own.
5. Rather than `[(j-1)*L:j*L]`, or even `[~-j*L:j*L]`, we can multiply by `L` once in the construction of `t` and just do `[j-L:j]`.

Comment: The oneliner is just for the fun to have few bytes and lines, it's totally ok if it does not increase the number of bytes.

Comment: The explanation of your code is great, thank you a lot for this helpful answer. I'll wait a few days before accepting.